# How can I convert a BibTex library to the bibliography format used by Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, bibtex

Are there ways to import BibTex files for use with the reference manager in Word?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.randomdetox.com/2008/06/using-bibtex-and-word-2007/

Comment: @Louis that is the method I am using now. But still not that convenient , want to try something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind [sharing](http://www.mendeley.com/privacy/) your bibliography with a third party, you could make use of Mendeley (or likely another reference manager software/service).

1. Import your BibTEX file into your Mendeley account: File > Add Files
2. [Install](http://support.mendeley.com/customer/portal/articles/168756-installing-and-using-the-word-plugin-in-windows) Mendeley Word plugin.  Once installed you'll have tool bar buttons that will allow you to generate a bibliography, among other things.

[Reference](http://download.mendeley.com/Getting_Started_Guide.pdf)